# How to aggregate String from docs into List of String

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Lets say I have ES records like this:

```
{
  "customerId": 1,
  "address": "hotel1:1, hotel2:2"
  "week" : 1
}
{
  "customerId": 2,
  "address": "hotel3:1, hotel4:2"
  "week" : 2
}
```

Now I want to concat address into 1

```
{
"customerId": 2,
 "address": "hotel3:1, hotel4:2", "hotel1:1, hotel2:2"
}
```

Is there a way in Elastic Search or Java API to concatenate strings while aggregating?

Comment: Can you show some code from what you have come up with so far and where you have trouble going forward?

Comment: I was trying to build up queries by using terms but that gives values as buckets. I dont have anything else as of now and there dont seem to be any such usecases online as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way in Elasticsearch to concatenate strings while aggregating

Your and my documents

```
PUT /concatenated_addresses/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"customerId":1,"address":"hotel1:1, hotel2:2","week":1}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"customerId":2,"address":"hotel3:1, hotel4:2","week":2}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"customerId":2,"address":"hotel5:1, hotel6:2","week":2}
```

Scripted metric query with address concatenation in a list

```
POST /concatenated_addresses/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "aggs": {
        "concatenated_addresses": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script": "state.addresses = new LinkedList()",
                "map_script": """
                    state.addresses.add(params['_source']['address'])
                """,
                "combine_script": "return state.addresses",
                "reduce_script": """
                    List concatenatedAddresses = new LinkedList();
                    for (addresses in states) {
                        concatenatedAddresses.addAll(addresses);
                    }
                    return concatenatedAddresses;
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "concatenated_addresses" : {
            "value" : [
                "hotel1:1, hotel2:2",
                "hotel3:1, hotel4:2",
                "hotel5:1, hotel6:2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can modify the `reduce_script` stage to return a string not a list